# How to stream 2 webcams through FFMPEG on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I like to stream 2 webcams from ffmpeg on windows to Flash media server in RTMP protocol.

I use FFMPEG to stream videos in a background vb.net by ProcessStartInfo , now I have a problem to use 2 FFMPEG to stream 2 webcams the same time.

When I run first FFMPEG it is run successfuly and it streams webcam1 correctly on the Media Server, when I want to start webcam2 to stream, the second ffmpegs in not runing.

This is my codes to start each FFMPEG:

```
Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("c:\ffmpeg.exe")
Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(psi)
psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.CreateNoWindow = True
psi.Arguments = " -f dshow -i video=""USB Camera"" -threads 1 -preset ultrafast -vcodec     libx264 -b:v 640k -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://12.11.1.6/live/sample1 "
proc = Process.Start(psi)
```

Please advise me to fix this problem

your help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you starting the first one?